# Can I have Django-1.2 use my LATIN1-encoded PostgreSQL database transparently?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a legacy PostgreSQL-7.4 database with its data stored encoded in LATIN1. It's used by more than just one app, so changing its encoding is problematic.

I've got a Django 1.2 app, using psycopg2 to access the database. Django wants to work entirely in Unicode, which I understand. Is there a way for me to tell Django the database's encoding, and have it translate between encodings for me between the app and the db? Is there a place I can hook to do that myself?

Comment: I have a similar problem using "MSSQL". How to tell Django that the database is actually Latin1?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify DATABASE_OPTIONS:

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    "charset": "iso-8859-1" #or latin1
}
```

From [Django legacy database encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267242/django-legacy-database-encoding/2269333#2269333)