# change data from latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, iconv

I have a database with data in latin1 encoding format. I am trying to convert all the data into utf-8 as missing some finnish, dansish characters. I tried with the following commands.

```
 mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 -u username -p -h example.com database_name > backup.sql
 iconv -f latin1 -t UTF-8 < backup.sql > converted-file.sql
```

but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
[link] http://stackoverflow.com/q/1440837/920359)

Comment: great !! these links helped me. thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: I tried this command but it is converting the data in the table. thanks.

Comment: where is your source data resided?