# Convert characters to UTF8 in MySQL (Ã© to é)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character, diacritics, latin

I've got a MySQL problem. My whole website except my database is in UTF8. I just recently tried to convert it to UTF8 with all kind of commands, but the main issue is still there:

the accents don't work. Instead of é, I've got Ã©. Same for è, there is another type of weird character.

Is there an easy to convert all these charaters, let's say Ã©, to é, in the base?

THanks a lot.

(by the way, the database is in latin1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Convert latin1 data to UTF8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440837/mysql-convert-latin1-data-to-utf8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, `Ã©` is `é` interpreted as LATIN1 and converted to UTF-8. It might be that your database is trying to be helpful and converts to UTF-8 where no conversion is required.

Have you tried switching the character set on your database tables?

Comment: Yes I have actually. It says it's in UTF8 but still the same issue. Weirdly. But is there a solution to convert the already existing characters to normal ones?

Comment: I've got an [answer for a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304485/how-to-detect-utf-8-characters-in-a-latin1-encoded-column-mysql) that addresses this. That could be switched to an `UPDATE` statement if you're feeling brave, and have backups.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try. I feel brave and I have backups, so why not :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this function :

```
CREATE TABLE `utf8decodemap` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `encoded` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `decoded` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY urlcodemapUIdx1(encoded),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
);

INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("â","Ã¢");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("é","Ã©");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("è","Ã¨");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ê","Ãª");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ë","Ã«");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("î","Ã®");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ï","Ã¯");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ô","Ã´");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ö","Ã¶");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ù","Ã¹");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("û","Ã»");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ü","Ã¼");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("ç","Ã§");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("œ","Å?");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("€","â¬");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("°","Â°");
INSERT INTO utf8decodemap (decoded,encoded) VALUES ("à","Ã");

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `utf8decoder`(str VARCHAR(4096)) RETURNS VARCHAR(4096) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
               DECLARE X  INT;               
               DECLARE chr VARCHAR(256);
               DECLARE chrto VARCHAR(256);
               DECLARE result VARCHAR(4096);
               SET X = 1;
               WHILE X  <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM utf8decodemap) DO
                   SET chr = (SELECT `encoded` FROM utf8decodemap WHERE id = X);
                   SET chrto = (SELECT `decoded` FROM utf8decodemap WHERE id = X);                
                           SET str = REPLACE(str,chr,chrto);
                           SET  X = X + 1;                           
               END WHILE;
               RETURN str;
       END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

ex : SELECT utf8decoder(MyCol) from MYtable

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the list above
and maybe this PHP script can help someone

1- solution A

```
$title = mb_convert_encoding($article['post_title'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

2- solution B

```
function convertSpacialChars($text)
{
    $charsMap = [
        "Ã¢" => "â",
        "Ã©" => "é",
        "Ã¨" => "è",
        "Ãª" => "ê",
        "Ã«" => "ë",
        "Ã®" => "î",
        "Ã¯" => "ï",
        "Ã´" => "ô",
        "Ã¶" => "ö",
        "Ã¹" => "ù",
        "Ã»" => "û",
        "Ã¼" => "ü",
        "Ã§" => "ç",
        "Å?" => "œ",
        "â¬" => "€",
        "Â°" => "°",
        "Ã" => "à",
    ];
    return str_replace(array_keys($charsMap),array_values($charsMap),$text);
}
```