# How to determine if there are foreign characters (not from English alphabet) in a string?

Tags: javascript, encoding

I am storing google maps result in my database and google sometimes return special characters so I tried doing the encodeURI(string) first before storing to database. However, it includes the spaces when encoding so it makes it difficult to read the values in the database.

[image]

As you can see, the spaces in some rows are also encoded as %20. How can identify which strings have special characters so only those rows will be encoded and the other rows using the same alphabet will remain the same? Is there any efficient approach to that?

Edited on March 10, 2014:
This is what I just did to solve this:

```
$unreadable_characters = array("%20", "%27", "%2E", "%2C", "_");
    $readable_characters = array(" ", "'", ".", ",", " ");
```

//and then use str_replace to change all those characters to their readable formats:

```
$keyword = str_replace($unreadable_characters, $readable_characters, $value[0]);
```

Using urldecode() when retrieving values from database still outputs the correct strings in the UI :)

Comment: rather than adding logic, you should try and get mysql to store the special characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440837/mysql-convert-latin1-data-to-utf8

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use a regex to check the alphabets:

```
var st = $('#id').val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(st) == false) {
    alert('string contains non english characters');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution! I think that's good!

Although what I just did is just replace them before inserting to database for a cleaner view like this:

        $unreadable_characters = array("%20", "%27", "%2E", "%2C", "_");
        $readable_characters = array(" ", "'", ".", ",", " ");

Comment: How to check if this string contains spaces as well?